# Eslint prettier issues

Tags: javascript, eslint, prettier, prettier-eslint

My eslint/prettier setup seems to be fixing things that it is not configured to fix, it’s doing a full replace of all semi-colons and single quotes but I don't believe that is included in our eslint/prettier setup. I have co-workers who run the same linter all the time (this was just pulled from master) so when I run it, it should not be making style changes to every js file in the project…

I know eslint supports hierarchies so, theoretically, a prettier file in my system might have been causing this to happen but I’ve added `"root": true` to the file and I continue to have the issue.

This is the `.eslintrc.json` file:

```
{
  "root": true, // <- this is the only change I've made
  "extends": [
    "airbnb-base",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],

  "plugins": [
    "react",
    "jsx-a11y",
    "prettier"
  ],

  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
      "modules": true
    }
  },

  "globals": {
    "document": true,
    "window": true
  }
}
```

---

Every time the above is run I get errors such like:

```
7:14  error  Replace `"form"` with `'form'`    prettier/prettier
9:2   error  Delete `;`                        prettier/prettier
```

I've tried running `yarn lint --debug` and I didn't see any outside linter/prettier scripts that would be overriding the above.

I'm not a JS expert by any means, I sort of believe that prettier is configured by default to remove semi-colons and double quotes but the fact that this does not happen for my coworkers leads me to believe that this configuration *should* disable that but it is not for me.

---

For further context, I do have the Prettier plugin for Atom but I have tried running this with it disabled and even uninstalled.  I've also uninstalled my global Prettier package.

Comment: what's your `prettierrc` config

Comment: what happens if you remove the lines with `"prettier"`  from your `extends` and `plugins` section?

Comment: @malarres the overall number of errors decreases by about 75, but it seems like many of the errors are still the same just not thrown by prettier: 

   `error  Strings must use singlequote                quotes`

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski there is no `prettierrc` file in the project.

Comment: @tfantina when you `extend` a given set you're adapting as default those rules. So the singlequotes are coming either from airbnb-base or react/recommended. You can test that by not extending at all

Comment: Hmm, thank you.  If I remove all extends the linter does throw fewer errors but it also dosen't lint the remaining errors are:
`17:1  error  Parsing error: The keyword 'import' is reserved`

Comment: We ended up adding specific prettier rules to `.eslintrc.json` to match my setup (fortunately it's a small team of me and one other dev working on this project and he was the one pushing to do this), it feels like a concession, I really wish I knew why this was happening.